# python 3 flask how to debug 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, flask

New to Python 3.7 RESTFUl API. In the following POST endpoint, I keep getting the following error message in the POST endpoint, but the GET endpoint works fine.

```
Exception in _query: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Wonder how can I debug this? There is no clear error message in SQL or Python. Thank you.

```
# all the imports
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
     render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__) # create the application instance :)
app.config.from_object(__name__) # load config from this file , flaskr.py

def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())

    print('create database successfully')
    db.commit()

# there are other codes in between being ignored

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def show_entries():

    try:
        db = get_db()
        # cur = db.execute('select  * from mouse_tracking')

        check_table="SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'mouse_tracking' and type = 'table'; "

        print(check_table)
        cur = db.execute(check_table)

        entries = cur.fetchall()

        print(type(entries))

        print(entries)

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Database error: %s" % e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception in _query: %s" % e)

    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)



@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():

    try:

        print('posting the content')

        db = get_db()
        db.execute('insert into mouse_tracking (user_id, date, x, y, click) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                     [request.form['user_id'], request.form['date'], request.form['x'], request.form['y']
                         , request.form['click']])
        db.commit()
        flash('New entry was successfully posted')

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Database error: %s" % e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception in _query: %s" % e)
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

Here is the show_entries.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  {% if session.logged_in %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
      <dl>
        <dt>Title:
        <dd><input type=text size=30 name=title>
        <dt>Text:
        <dd><textarea name=text rows=5 cols=40></textarea>
        <dd><input type=submit value=Share>
      </dl>
    </form>
  {% endif %}
  <ul class=entries>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>{{ entry.text|safe }}
  {% else %}
    <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

here is the curl call

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/add' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic cm9vdDpkZWZhdWx0' \
--data-raw '{
    "user_id": "1",
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "x": "720",
    "y": "50",
    "click": "0"
}'
```

Here is the schema.sql

```
create table if not exists mouse_tracking (
  user_id integer not null,
  date timestamp not null,
  x integer not null,
  y integer not null,
  click integer not null
);
```

Comment: Your POST /add expects a form not application/json.
Try: 

application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: i see. if i want to make it expects JSON application, how could i change it? thank you!

Comment: Thank you @ionheart I just figure it out! ``` @app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():

    reqjson = request.json

    user_id=reqjson['user_id']```